# Escape table name in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, escaping

I have table named References in SQLite, so I can't target it, it seems. SQLite studio I use to edit databases throws an error.

Is there a way to escape database name?

The query is:

```
UPDATE References 
SET DateTimeLastEdited = datetime('now', 'localtime')
WHERE NewsItemID = old.NewsItemID;
```

(This is part of the trigger I am making.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can escape table names with double quotes:

```
UPDATE "References" SET DateTimeLastEdited = datetime('now', 'localtime') WHERE NewsItemID = old.NewsItemID;
```

Depending on what you want to escape, you need to use different delimiters:

> If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it. There
> are four ways of quoting keywords in SQLite:
>
> 'keyword'     A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
>
> "keyword"     A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
>
> [keyword]     A
> keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is not
> standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access and SQL
> Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
>
> `keyword`       A
> keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an identifier.
> This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MySQL and
> is included in SQLite for compatibility.

From [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)