# Escape table name of attached database in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite, escaping

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884362/escape-table-name-in-sqlite), you can escape a table name by putting double-quotes around it.  The [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) further states that brackets and back-ticks are also possible for compatibility with other systems.

This works on tables from the current database, however, when I try to do this on an attached database I get an error:

```
ATTACH db2 AS x; SELECT * FROM "x.table1";
```

yields the error:

```
no such table: x.table1
```

If I remove the "x." and run the query directly on database db2, it works.

So how do I escape the table name when it is part of an attached database?

I have tried the brackets and backticks, and I have also tried quoting only the table name and not the "x." part, e.g. all of the following:

```
ATTACH db2 AS x; SELECT * FROM `x.table1`;
ATTACH db2 AS x; SELECT * FROM [x.table1];
ATTACH db2 AS x; SELECT * FROM x."table1";
ATTACH db2 AS x; SELECT * FROM x.`table1`;
ATTACH db2 AS x; SELECT * FROM x.[table1];
```

None of these work.

Comment: Please show an example of how you tried to quote only the table name.

Comment: @CL. I have added all of the additional things I tried before posting.

Comment: The last three work.

Comment: @CL. They didn't work for me and yielded the same error as the first try, hence why I posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me:

`select * from "x"."table1";`

Comment: Yes, that is it!  Thank you.