# What are SQLite3 special characters?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create SQL statements dynamically in my C++ program using a self-made placeholder syntax. However, there are some special SQL-specific or SQLite3-specific characters, which I should not use. Can you please help me to make such a list? My aim is to find a character which cannot occur in an SQL statement. I am mainly using SQLite3, but this might change in the future.

This is what I have found out so far:

- LIKE: % _ (within string literals)
- GLOB: ? * (within string literals)
- SQLite3 Parameter Binding: ? : @ $
- Statements: ; ,
- String Literals: '
- Operations: + - * / > < = ~ & | !

Possible Candidates include:

- ^
- #
- "
- /
- \

Comment: Some of that is not possible to answer because how to specify parameter bindings might differ by the surrounding runtime and programming language. Also, for the things that are specified by SQLite, you should really just check the documentation [here](http://sqlite.org/lang.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please don't think that I did not check the documentation. There I found the above characters. I just want to make sure that I did not miss one. Finding one for SQLite alone would suffice. By the way, my scenario is C++ and SQLite3.

Comment: Your question is unclear about where inside a statement you think the listed characters should be avoided. Surely they can't be used for designators (field and table names), but SQLite shouldn't even let you create these.

Answer (score 3):

*All* characters can occur inside string literals.

Comment: Correct. I should therefore parse the SQL statement and ignore string literals. What characters can occur outside string literals?

Answer (score 0):

What constructs are allowed in a SQL statement is partly DBMS/dialect specific; for SQLite a good starting point is here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

If DB, table or field names contain special characters they need to be [escaped/quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467644/escape-table-name-of-attached-database-in-sqlite), string literals have been addressed by CL before, and the rest is [keywords](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), operators, numerical values and valid designators (names and functions), which are restricted to a subset of the ASCII character set. So everything else is invalid, but if your SQL dialect defines backslash as a (non-standard) operator it is valid.